# Why do the middat hayom start with chessed and progress to malchut?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, malchut-royalty, middos-character-traits, chesed-kindness

Included in my siddur as part of the sefirat haomer are the corresponding middat hayom for each day/week. They begin with chessed sh'b'chessed and progress through a series of middot - gevurah, tiferes, netzach, hod, yesod, malchut. From what I understand the order of the middot actually progresses in the opposite direction with Chessed being of a "higher" order and Malchut being the lowest rung. Assuming this is correct (and I do not have a source to prove that it is) why would we begin with the middah of chessed and progress "downward" instead of starting at malchut and proceed higher?

Answer (score 1):

Omer is the time when we so-to-speak recreate ourselves in accordance with the Divine Will, so the creative process is a good represenation of what is spiritually happening during the time between Pesach and Shavuos.

The *middos* represent, in one sense, the stages of realization of that creative process. It starts with the highest forms (here, *chessed*) and proceeds to implementation until the lowest form of the implementation is complete (here, *malchus*).